# Mark Attendance without notifying the user through website

Tags: asp.net

I am developing a web application for Hr & Payroll.
In which Attendance is marked through Biometrics Device..
The Problem is that at times user forget to punch the device and on the basis of that their salary is deducted from their account..
So to avoid this I have thought of an idea of marking attendance..is it possible that i use each n every employee IP address in my web application so that whenever a computer is switched on in a day for the first time that timing should get saved in My Database.
And when that computer is switched off for the last time than that attendance should also be marked in database..but i dont know how to do this..is this even possible.??.
Cause this will give a gr8 functionality to the companies hr department..n their will be no legl hassles..
please throw some light on this

Answer (score 1):

You need to create [window services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a.aspx) for this task.

Here is a good example with the step by step process of creating window service
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample

We had similar situation in our organization.
We read the attendance table with a window scheduler at particular time. And sent the mail if user have not marked the attendance.

Answer (score 0):

Do the users need to log on to a system somewhere? How about logging on to the network or computer? You could write a little quick and dirty that runs when the person logs in (you could make it run hidden) that would save something to the database.

The problem comes from when they leave. What I've usually done is have something that will update a record every 5 minutes that writes a ping/I'm here! to a record. Then at some point you could see - this is when we first started getting messages (they logged on) and here's where they stopped (have to assume they logged off). You could even do some kind of session ID so that you could have multiple records for the person.

You could make this a program that either runs completely in the background or appears in the notification area.

Comment: But shekhar wont it conflict..suppose i have made this windows service..and i schedule that windows service to run after every 5 minutes.so that it could save that in database..do not you think for every single employee there will be so many rows entered as the windows service will be marking his attendance after every 5 minutes...